# How to handle different targets for same directories in parallel making

Tags: makefile, parallel-processing, gnu

The question is about parallel making w/ GNU makefile.

Given a folder structure as below, the goal is to deliver a makefile that it supports make release/debug/clean in parallel.

project folder structure:

```
   foo  
     +-foo1
     +-foo2
     +-foo3
```

The makefile may be sth like:

```
SUBDIR = foo1 foo2 foo3
.PHONY $(SUBDIR) release debug clean
release: $(SUBDIR)
$(SUBDIR):
     $(MAKE) -C $@ release

debug: $(SUBDIR)
#below is incorrect. $(SUBDIR) is overriden.
$(SUBDIR):
     $(MAKE) -C $@ debug
..
```

Sub directory list are set as phony targets for parallel making. but it lost the information of original target (release, debug, clean etc).

One method is to suffix the names for the directories and recover it in commands, but it is weird.  another method might be to use variables, but not sure how to work it out.

The questions is:
How to write the rules for directories, that supports parallel making w/ different targets (release/debug/clean)?

Any hints are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Never mind. I work it out by passing variables. debug: \n  \n $(MAKE) -C $@ sub_target=debug

Answer (score 0):

Setting variables on the command line certainly works.  You can also use MAKECMDGOALS (see the GNU make manual):

```
$(SUBDIR):
        $(MAKE) -C $@ $(MAKECMDGOALS)
```